# How to erase the text in Pixelmator if the text is not generated within Pixelmator?

Tags: pixelmator

How can I erase the text that is not generated in Pixelmator? In the following image, what I like to do is erase the black status bar text (carrier, Wi-Fi symbol, time, and battery icon) on the top of the screen. However, I cannot use the eraser tool because it's basically impossible to use the exactly same color as the navigation bar on the screen, and if it's not the exact same color, the resultant image is quite ugly on which everyone can easily recognize there were some texts there before being erased.

So is it feasible to erase the text as if it's not there in the first place?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several options:

- select part of the gray background, and clone/copy it to cover the text you don't want.
- use the eyedropper tool to select the gray background, and then paint over the text with that color
- use the clone tool to clone a blank part of the gray background over the text part
- use the eyedropper tool to select the gray background, then create a vector shape (rectangle) with that color to cover the text.
- and I'm sure there's other options as well...

Keep in mind that there is no 'text' there in the sense of the text tool. The text tool creates actual editable text that is rasterized 'on the fly'. If the text is already part of an image layer, the software just sees those as pixels. The eraser tool erases pixels and doesn't really care if they are black or gray...so that won't work.

Comment: What's the `clone` tool? Do you mean `clone stamp` tool?

Comment: And I just found that it's probably the easiest to just use `Rectangular Marquee` Tool, select one part of the extra gray area, and copy and create the new layer using the selected part, and cover the text part of the original image with the created layer. Thanks.